# Expected primary-expression before "else" error

Tags: c++, if-statement

I get the `expected primary-expression before "else"` error for the first else and I do not understand why. I triple checked all the bracing.

```
if(Owin = win)
{
    cout << "The computer has defeated you!\n\n";
    cout << "Would you like to play again? (Y or N) : ";
    cin >> restart;
    if(restart == 'Y' || restart == 'y');
    {
        cout << "\n\n\n";
        main()    ;
    }

    else
    {
        cout << "Good Bye!\n\n";
        system("pause");
        return(0);
    }
}
else
{
}
```

Comment: You can't call `main` recursively like that, and your compiler should warn you about the single equals sign in your if.

Comment: (Using a decent programming editor with "auto indenting" would likely show this trivial mistake. It would also make the code *much* more readable.)

Comment: actually chris i can call main like that... it is inside main

Answer (score 2):

```
if(restart == 'Y' || restart == 'y');
```

Remove the semicolon there to fix the error. This `;` ends your `if` statement, which means the `else` is actually not part of any `if` statement, hence the error.

Comment: You get paid to answer? that was super quick! thank you so much!!!

Comment: @user1914650 its just lucky timing :) you are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

In your code,

```
if(restart == 'Y' || restart == 'y');
```

the trailing semicolon is an **empty statement** that forms the body of (and thus ends) the `if` block. At this point you could have had an `else`. But not after a subsequent statement that's not an `if`.

Further, and *more importantly*, in your code, the call

```
main()    ;
```

assuming it calls the `main` in the global namespace, is invalid. **`main`** (in the global namespace) is a special function. Among its special properties is that it can't be called.

The compiler may allow it without any diagnostic, but formally you then have **Undefined Behavior** where anything can happen.

Instead, use a loop to achieve repetition.

Answer (score 1):

You have a trailing semicolon after your `if` statement.