# The if statement is always executed?

Tags: c++, if-statement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Expected primary-expression before “else” error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13945190/expected-primary-expression-before-else-error)

So when i try to go around the first if statement to continue the rest of the program, it always performs the first if statement, i was just wondering if what im doing with the else works or not. I have already tried including the rest of my code in the else statement but it that does not work either. There is no compiler error so PLEASE HELP! thank you!

```
if(Owin = win)
{
    cout << "The computer has defeated you!\n\n";
    cout << "Would you like to play again? (Y or N) : ";
    cin >> restart;
    if(restart == 'Y' || restart == 'y');
    {  
        cout << "\n\n\n";
        main()    ;  
    }

    else 
    {   
        cout << "Good Bye!\n\n";
        system("pause");
        return(0);
    }  
}
else
{ }
```

Comment: Did you mean "==" instead of "="?

Comment: Of course it performs the `if`. The problem is that why does the expression *inside* if always evaluates to true (or am I not getting your point).

Comment: sorry about the dumb question

Comment: Actually, the above shouldn't even compile.  The `else` statement has no predecessor.

Comment: It is not legal to call `main`.

Answer (score 2):

You used `=` instead of `==`. So you're just assigning `win` to `Owin`, which is always true for the `if`, if `Owin > 0`.

Also, remove the `;`  from the second `if`.

It's also superfluous to write `else { }` because you're doing nothing inside the `else`.

As a template, this would be better:

```
int main()
{
    // Declarations...

    while(restart != 'Y' && restart != 'y')
    {
        if(Owin == win)
        {
            cout << "The computer has defeated you!\n\n";
            cout << "Would you like to play again? (Y or N) : ";
            cin >> restart;
        }
        else 
        {
            // Do the rest here
        }
    }
    cout << "Good Bye!\n\n";
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Incorrect syntax of if statement
correct syntax of if statement is

```
if(condition)
{
 //body of if statement
}
```

you have to use checking operators like == not =
the condition of if should return boolean

= is to initialize and == is for checking whether two things are equal
instead otherwise use

```
if(Owin > 0)
```

or use

```
if(Owin == win)
```

Answer (score 0):

`if(Owin = win)` will always be true if `win` is not zero/null, since that assigns `win` to `Owin` and then checks the value of `Owin` and considers an non-zero/non-null value to be `TRUE`.